# How do I remove Wolfram Branding in a CDF?

Tags: cdf-format, stylesheet, enterprise-cdf

I have a *Mathematica* Enterprise License, which lets me export Pro-feature CDFs. One of the benefits is supposed to be removal of branding and full customization of UI. Does anyone know how to get that done? Because in Player and in Plugin, I'm still getting the Wolfram Bar and all the usual stuff.

Comment: Seems to me to be an issue you should take up with WRI support.

Comment: Here is faster!

Comment: @Murta The information I was given by wolfram was that CDF enterprise users had 24 hour tech support. However I didn't read the fine print -- so maybe this means you can ask a question 24/7 but it doesn't mean you get an answer any faster :)

Comment: They have a very fast support in the Enterprise, I use it a lot and I'm happy with it. But SE can be even faster! :)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is the sequence of commands that I use to create my CDFs.

```
testCDF := DynamicModule[... some nice code]

nb = CreateDocument[{testCDF}
    ,Visible -> False
    ,WindowTitle->"Export Test"
    ,WindowMargins->Automatic
    ,WindowSize->Automatic
    ,WindowElements->{"VerticalScrollBar","HorizontalScrollBar"}
    ,ShowCellBracket->False
    ,Deployed->True
];

(*options to remove wolfram toolbar*)
SetOptions[nb, PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"PluginToolbarEnabled" -> False}];

CDFDeploy[NotebookDirectory[] <> "ExportTests2.cdf", 
  nb,
  "Method"->"Standalone",
  "Target"->"PlayerPro"
];

NotebookClose[nb];
```

The command to remove Wolfram bar is commented.

Comment: I wanted to say that this is my favourite answer, in terms of how many times I was using this information. :) I have also a question, do you know how to avoid creating .png files while creating cdfs?

Comment: tks! I'm glad that is was an useful answer. What do you mean by "create .png files". What kind of png it's creating?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm trying to handle to many things at once and I'm forgetting about minor ones... till the next occurence :) Well, at least on Win, when I'm deploying CDF there is allways a png file created with the output and overlayed banner "get the cdf player". I don't need it, or maybe it is important?

Comment: @Kuba, sorry, I'm using it on Mac, I don't get this banner.

Comment: Ok, thanks for info. I'll post the question in the future then. Have a good day.

Comment: This is very useful, but it does not remove the initial welcome screen.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino, they are working on it. CDF player 10 should have this and another nice news.

Comment: @Murta thanks for the info! Let's hope the wait is not much longer. I am now forced to use version 9 knowing that several things in 10 would make my work much easier.