# Programmatic generation of enhanced (Enterprise) CDF

Tags: export, cdf-format, enterprise-cdf

How does one PROGRAMATICALLY generate enhanced CDFs under an Enterprise license?  Undocumented options to CDFDeploy[] perhaps?. Wizard works fine for me, but attempts to do this programatically (from script) have defeated me - I just get standard CDFs labeled under the FreeCDF terms (this result with no code changes.)  Can't find this in documentation.

Comment: See [this] (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20492/29) answer. The secret is the option `"Target"->"PlayerPro"` of CDFDeploy.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: since you have an EnterpriceMathematica license you should really ask these questions directly to Wolfram. You can also call them, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

I use this sequence of commands to generate Enterprise CDF:

```
(*Export to CDF*)
nb=CreateDocument[{myCDFGenerationFunction[]}
    ,WindowTitle->"My Title"
    ,WindowMargins->Automatic
    ,WindowSize->Automatic
    ,WindowElements->{"VerticalScrollBar","HorizontalScrollBar"}
    ,ShowCellBracket->False
    ,Deployed->True
    (*,WindowFrameElements -> {}*)(*Window does't close!*)
];

SetOptions[nb
    ,PrivateNotebookOptions -> {"PluginToolbarEnabled" -> False}
    ,Background -> GrayLevel[0.2]
];

CDFDeploy[NotebookDirectory[]<>"CDFFileName.cdf",nb
 ,"Method"->"Standalone"
 ,"Target"->"PlayerPro"
];

NotebookClose[nb];
```

As @RolfMertig said, the "secret" is in `"Target"->"PlayerPro"` inside `CDFDeploy`.